# Reading(/Writing) Files in C#

Tags: c#, file-io

I recently wanted to track progress of a `HTTPWebRequest` Upload progress. So I started small and started with buffered read of a simple text file. I then discovered that a simple task like

```
File.ReadAllText("text.txt");
```

becomes something like below, with all the streams, readers, writers etc. Or can somethings be removed? Also the code below is not working. Maybe I did something wrong, whats the way to read (i guess write will be similar) into buffer so that I can track progress, assuming the stream are not local eg. WebRequest

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[2560]; // 20KB Buffer, btw, how should I decide the buffer size?
int bytesRead = 0, read = 0;
FileStream inStream = new FileStream("./text.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();
BinaryWriter outWriter = new BinaryWriter(outStream);

// I am getting "Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection."
// inStream.Length = Length = 9335092
// bytesRead = 2560
// buffer.Length = 2560
while ((read = inStream.Read(buffer, bytesRead, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    outWriter.Write(buffer);
    //outStream.Write(buffer, bytesRead, buffer.Length);
    bytesRead += read;
    Debug.WriteLine("Progress: " + bytesRead / inStream.Length * 100 + "%");
}
outWriter.Flush();

txtLog.Text = outStream.ToString();
```

**Update: Solution**

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[2560];
int bytesRead = 0, read = 0;
FileStream inStream = File.OpenRead("text.txt");
MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();

while ((read = inStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    outStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    bytesRead += read;
    Debug.WriteLine((double)bytesRead / inStream.Length * 100);
}

inStream.Close();
outStream.Close();
```

Comment: "Also the code below is not working." - how about helping yourself and explaining what is not working as expected...?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat, oh I forgot to add the error, I updated the post. I get the error on the `while` line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should probably be

```
outWriter.Write(buffer,0,read);
```

Comment: Also, why is `offset` 0? should it be `bytesRead` instead? else thro the loop, it will overwrite written data?

Comment: Oh, maybe you meant, `inStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)`? cos this fixes the problem

Comment: Oh and if I use `outStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);` will work

Comment: i can't tell if i helped or not any more ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be reading text (although I could be wrong), it seems that your program could be a lot simpler if you read character by character instead of calling the standard Read():

```
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open("./text.txt", FileMode.Open));
MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();
StreamWriter outWriter = new StreamWriter(outStream);

while (Reader.BaseStream.Position < Reader.BaseStream.Length)
{
    outWriter.Write(reader.ReadChar());
    Debug.WriteLine("Progress: " + ((double)reader.BaseStream.Position) / (double)(reader.BaseStream.Length) + "%");
}
outWriter.Close();
txtLog.Text = outStream.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you only need to check the progress of the upload operation you can just check the size of the file using a fileinfo object.

In the FileInfo class theres a property called length that returns the file size in bytes. Not sure if it gives the current size when the file being written. But I think it'll be worth giving a try as it is more simple and efficient than the method that you are using